# Starting a batch file in a new window from a batch file, and keeping the new window open after completion

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

EDIT: I will try to make it clearer what I actually want.

I have some very long batch files that I want to run in order and only starting after the previous one had completed.

I am trying to control this with a master batch file

I want them starting each in their own window which remains open after completion to look back later

In numerical order:

1.run main batch file

2.open new cmd window

3.run batch file 1

4.waiting for 1 to finish

5.1 finished, keep window open

6.open another new cmd window

7.run batch2
etc

-- original message --

Hi so I have a windows batch file that needs to run other windows batch files sequentially and wait for them to finish before starting the next one.

Something like:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    
SET RUN="C:first.bat"
start /wait cmd /c %RUN%

SET RUN="C:second.bat"
start /wait cmd /c %RUN%
```

where first and second for example just echo something like:

```
@echo off
echo 1st
exit /b 0
```

When I run this it starts the first script in a new window and keeps the window open after completing like I want, but to progress to the second script I have to close the new cmd window.

How can I make the main batch script start the second.bat without closing the first.bat cmd window?

Thanks

Comment: Could you not use the `Call` command? Please open a Command Prompt window, type `call /?` and press the `[ENTER]` key, to find out what it does, and how it works. If they really do need to be run in new windows, then those windows would be `cmd.exe`, windows and if you want one of those to open and remain open you'd need its `/K` option. However, if it remains open `/Wait` is going to prevent the next sequential command from running, isn't it?

Comment: What do you think the `/WAIT` option is doing?  You told the script to wait for cmd.exe to finish before it can move onto the next command in the batch file.

Comment: @Compo call does not open a new window, I don't want lots of log spam in one window

Comment: I know what `Call` does, @TheFroggler8888, I was simply asking if you could use it. Please also read my entire content, not just a small portion of it.

Comment: @Compo I also know what call does which is why I'm not using it, I need some way to break out of the wait at the end of the script while still keeping the window open. I did not ask to run everything in one window.

Comment: @TheFroggler8888, you might want to review the output of `CMD /?` and check out what the `/K` switch does.

Comment: `start "" cmd /k "ping localhost"` is a good example of such usage.

Comment: @TheFroggler8888, whilst it is good to see that you've tried to edit your question for better clarification, it would be better if you could explain what the particular issue is with using the `/K` option as mentioned. I would by now have expected you to have submitted some code using it, and any debugging information related to that use.

Comment: @compo as you said in your post that you edited after I replied to you
"if you want one of those to open and remain open you'd need its /K option. However, if it remains open /Wait is going to prevent the next sequential command from running, isn't it?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a very unusual requirement that

1. other batch files should not be processed by the `cmd.exe` instance processing the main batch file, but by other instances of `cmd.exe` just to have their outputs in a different console window and
2. keep each other command process running after finishing the processing of the batch file to be able to view their outputs in their console windows and
3. wait with further processing of main batch file until processing of a batch file finished by the started separate command process, but do not wait for termination of the started other command processes.

The Windows command processor `cmd.exe` is not designed for a serialized multi-processing of batch files with multiple instances of itself which finally should keep running.

However, here are three batch files which demonstrate that this is possible with one disadvantage explained later.

**Main.bat**

```
@echo off & goto Main

:WaitForBatch
start "Run %~nx1" %ComSpec% /D /S /K "(%ComSpec% /D /C "%~1") & title Finished %~n1"
echo Waiting for finished execution of "%~nx1" ...
:CheckBatchRun
%WaitCommand% >nul
%SystemRoot%\System32\tasklist.exe /NH /FI "IMAGENAME eq cmd.exe" /V | %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /I "%~nx1" >nul
if errorlevel 1 goto :EOF
goto CheckBatchRun

:Main
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
title Run %~nx0
if exist %SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe (
    set "WaitCommand=%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 1"
) else (
    set "WaitCommand=%SystemRoot%\System32\ping.exe 127.0.0.1 -n 2"
)
call :WaitForBatch "%~dp0First.bat"
call :WaitForBatch "%~dp0Second.bat"
title Finished %~n0
pause
endlocal
```

**First.bat**

```
@echo off
dir %SystemRoot% /B /S
```

**Second.bat**

```
@echo off
dir %SystemRoot%\*.exe
echo(
pause
```

`Main.bat` is coded in a manner expecting `First.bat` and `Second.bat` in the same directory as `Main.bat`, but the other batch files can be also in different directories. The current directory on execution of the three batch files can be any directory.

`Main.bat` first sets up the execution environment for itself which is:

1. command echo mode turned off and
2. command extensions enabled and
3. delayed expansion disabled.

The window title of the console window of `cmd.exe` processing `Main.bat` is modified to show `Run Main.bat` at beginning.

Next is determined if command **TIMEOUT** is available in which case this command will be used later for a delay of one second (Windows Vista and later Windows client versions) or if command **PING** must be used for the one second delay (Windows XP).

Then the subroutine `WaitForBatch` is called the first time with the batch file `First.bat`.

The subroutine uses the command **START** to start one more command process in a new console window with window title `Run First.bat` with ignoring the `AutoRun` registry string value which by Windows default does not exist.

This second `cmd.exe` instance keeps running after execution of the command line specified next with the other arguments is finished. The command line for second `cmd.exe` requires the execution of a third `cmd.exe` again with ignoring `AutoRun` registry string value if existing at all to execute the batch file `First.bat` specified with fully qualified file name. The third `cmd.exe` instances closes itself on finishing processing of the batch file.

The second `cmd.exe` changes now the title of its console window to `Finished First`. Important is here that the batch file extension is not anymore in the window title.

The first `cmd.exe` instance processing `Main.bat` continues with batch file processing already after successful start of second `cmd.exe`. It uses the command to wait one second and then runs **TASKLIST** to output all running `cmd.exe` processes with verbose information which is redirected to command **FIND** to search case-insensitive for the batch file name `First.bat`.

As long as there is a `cmd.exe` process running with `First.bat`, the first `cmd.exe` continues batch file processing of `Main.bat` inside subroutine `WaitForBatch` in a loop with a jump to `CheckBatchRun`. Otherwise the subroutine is left and processing of `Main.bat` continues with the second **CALL** of `WaitForBatch` with `Second.bat`.

Finally `Main.bat` changes also its window title to `Finished Main` and prompts the user to press any key in case of `Main.bat` execution was started with a double click on this file in Windows Explorer.

`First.bat` takes a very long time to finish as thousands of file names must be output into the console window of second `cmd.exe`. It is possible to click on the **X** symbol of console window with title `Run First.bat` to terminate immediately the execution of second and of third `cmd.exe` which results in first `cmd.exe` continues with starting two more `cmd.exe` for processing `Second.bat`.

It is also possible to interrupt the long running `First.bat` by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> and answer the prompt for termination of batch job with <kbd>Y</kbd> (on English Windows) resulting in third `cmd.exe` stopping really the processing of `First.bat` and second `cmd.exe` keeps running showing the output of `First.bat` and changing the window title of its console window to `Finished First`. This is detected by first `cmd.exe` processing `Main.bat` and it starts the processing of `Second.bat`.

The disadvantage of this solution is that on pressing <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> in console window with title `Run First.bat` while **DIR** outputs all the file names and pressing now <kbd>N</kbd> (on English Windows) results nevertheless in a termination of the batch job. I am not 100% sure why this happens. I have just a supposition for this behavior.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `call /?`
- `cmd /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `find /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `ping /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `start /?`
- `tasklist /?`
- `timeout /?`
- `title /?`

Comment: Thank you, I understand it is very much a nonstandard case, very detailed answer it is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Construct main batch 1 with early commands (one line each) for each secondary batch 2 WINDOWTITLE:

TASKLIST /FI "WINDOWTITLE EQ <batch #>" | Find "cmd.exe" > NUL & GOTO someplace

Have above lines in reverse order of operation = last batch to run listed first

**Then:**

1. start main batch 1
2. when wanted START batch 2 and EXIT batch 1
3. last commands in batch 2:
   Start main batch 1 & cmd /k
4. repeat as necessary